# Making a StackPanel scrollable in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, height, windows-phone, stackpanel

I have a list of controls, put into a stackpanel. These controls are Hubtiles, that are added programatically after a user creates it - a list essentially. I need to make the StackPanel in which they are added, scrollable - what would be the best approach for this? Should i put the stackpanel inside a ScrollView, and then increase the StackPanels height with the actual height of the Hubtile - to make it scrollable, but not so that the user can scroll infinite without something being there. So whenever the amount of controls inside the StackPanel reaches 3, it'll automatically increase it's height like this:

Whenever the amount of controls inside the StackPanel reaches 3 or above:

```
StackPanel.Height = StackPanel.Height + Hubtile.ActualHeight;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried making the StackPanels height automatic and wrapping it in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: Maybe i could try making it automatic, haven't tried yet - hold on, i'll try

Comment: While you're on it, try to change the background color so you have a visual feedback on its actual height. Using colors is always the easiest way to "debug" size-related problems.

Comment: Worked perfectly, wonder why i didn't think of putting the height to Auto. The color tip was also a smart trick, it expanded well. You should download my app when i'm done since u've helped me so much - REALLY appreciate it:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just **put the StackPanel into ScrollViewer**, set the StackPanel.VerticalAlignment to Stretch and set fixed size to the parent ScrollViewer. This is necessary - the ScrollViewer must know its size, to show the scrollbars for the inner content when the inner content is too long.