# ListBox Like Touch Scrolling for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

The WPF ListBox has some very nice touch scrolling functionality built in, that I want to use on a simple ItemsControl.

I'd strongly prefer to use the existing functionality to achieve this, since my previous efforts (using the TouchDown/Move/Up events) have not been as smooth as the behavior of the ListBox, and felt different enough to be recognizable in an application using both controls.

I tried locating the code responsible for the ListBox touch behaviour in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), but the ListBox class does not even contain the word "Touch".

Is there a way to enable touch scrolling on the ItemsControl, or, if there is not, where is the magic code responsible for the ListBox hidden so that I can port it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PanningMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792695(v=vs.100).aspx) property of the ScrollViewer used (either inside the ControlTemplate, or outside the ItemsControl) needs to be set to something other than "None".

The code responsible for the touch scrolling can be found in the class [System.Windows.Input.InertiaTranslationBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inertiatranslationbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer` and make sure touch events bubble up to the `ScrollViewer` from any controls within the `ItemsControl`

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I've added an ScrollViewer to the ItemsControl's template. But no luck. I'll check where the Touch events are going with Snoop...

Comment: Snoop tells me that nothing in the visual tree handles these touch events. When I put the ScrollViewer outside, nothing changes except that my virtualization does not work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

as they said, you need tu put your ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer, but if you want that to do what you want, you have to set the height of your itemsControl.
look at this post : [Making a StackPanel scrollable in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176799/making-a-stackpanel-scrollable-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but my problem is the "touch" part of "touch scrolling". The "scrolling" part works fine. =)

Comment: I think this is a WPF issue, not WP8?